# Cannot understand this definition

Tags: meaning

I recently got a book about epistemology and I cannot make heads or tails of what this definition means:

CAUSAL: <cat> denotes cats = cats, cause, under appropriate conditions, mental tokenings of <cat>.

Can anyone please translate this to simpler English?

Comment: You are missing parts of the quote. The `<cats>`. The quote is `CAUSAL: <cats> denotes cats = cats, cause, under appropriate conditions, mental tokenings of <cats>.`

Comment: I tried to write that, but the cats between the brackets were removed, how can i prevent this?

Comment: You can use `&lt;` to get a `<`, and `&gt;` to get a `>`.

Comment: This question fits better with the [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) website. The syntax of that definition is particular of that book, and perhaps the area, but no of English. From what read in that section it looks like it should be read as: '<ca> denotes cats' means that cats, cause, under appropriate conditions, mental tokenings of <cat>. Here <cat> is the representation of cats, like the word "cat". 'Mental tokenings' means an instance of a mental representation of a cat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about epistemology rather than the English language. From a linguistic point of view, there is nothing strange or difficult about the sentence. The difficulty lies in understanding what it’s actually supposed to **mean**, and that requires knowledge of epistemology, rather than English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet obviously you're entitled to that view, but I'd argue that it is impenetrable for reasons other than requiring special knowledge, though having the concept explained in an alternative way can bypass the failures of the sentence, so could a better construction. (That's not to say I believe I constructed a better explanation, sadly)

Comment: It's a formalism, and it can't be interpreted without a formal guide to the particular formalism used. See [`Notation: Logical`](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-LogicalNotation.pdf). Cf Macintosh <--> Windows file transfers.

Comment: @JohnLawler The OP did not ask to be taught how to interpret, they asked for an interpretation. Though the link will no doubt be useful to the OP...if they choose to make use of it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about philosophy, not ELU.

Comment: Although this sentence has the form of a definition, it is not a definition of the kind one finds in dictionaries; it is a part of explicating a philosophical theory. Related: [Are questions about explaining what the text mean on-topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14978/are-questions-about-explaining-what-the-text-mean-on-topic/14979#14979).

Answer (score 0):

It just means that cat, the word & the meaning is created by prior experience of cat.

> CAUSAL: <cat> denotes cats = cats, cause, under appropriate conditions, mental tokenings of <cat>.

CAUSAL(Explanation): The mental experience encapsulated by the term 'cat' is informed by our prior experience of 'cat.'

We use different methods to explain the truth of different things. Causal logic is one such tool.

From:
https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/truth-as-one-and-many/

> REPRESENT: The belief that α is F is true if and only if the object denoted by α has the property denoted by F.

(see: Cat & Cats, Sun & Sunny)

> The overall picture of truth given here is abstract. But of course, that is part of the point. This book has been about truth itself -- and truth itself, the functionalist theory claims, is a rather abstract property. But it is also a property that comes in more than one form. If that is right, then philosophical progress lies in investigating those forms, in discovering how truth manifests itself across the spectrum of our thought.

Lynch is exploring how people describe and relate to their world(and the virtues and flaws of those methods).

I'm not sure whether Lynch begins with that example, it might be worth reading on to discover how he defines other cognitive/descriptive/philosophical methodologies such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology (and then compare and contrast)